# This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store

Tags: security, browser, ssl, certificate, https

I am running a web app on Linux where I dont think anyone will look at it besides myself called node red looking to run the web app on TLS with certs.

Going off this [tutorial](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000018152) to generate these two files: `key.pem cert.pem` that are required to run the web app on TLS/SSL from this [tutorial](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red).

My browser throws this error, I think because I am not using a Trusted CA. Is there a way for the browser to ignore this or add it to a list of trusted sites/CA on my Windows 10 PC that I use to check the web app in Chrome?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyone can create a self-signed certificate for every domain. If I follow your procedure with let’s say microsoft.com, will this make a trustfully certificate ?

Then there are multiple options :

- distribute your certificate via a trustred channel to all your client and make them install it in their trusted certificate base, (the procedure  depends of your navigator, and perhaps needs a DER format certificate instead of PEM. OpenSSL can translate it for you)
- purchase a certificate which is trusted by most navigators,
- use letsencrypt. (https://letsencrypt.org/)

The last two options seems me preferable, but if you persist with the first option, the actual navigator you use  is a needed information.

For example, on Windows for IE or Edge, you open MMC, add a plugin certificate and add a certificate among the trusted root certification authorities. (Trusted Root certification authorities/certificates/right click:all tasks/import)

On Firefox, in the main menu (right top, just under the cross to close the window), options, privacy and security, views certificates, import.

The `cert.pem` Is the required file.

Comment: The Windows store also covers Chrome (per Q) and instead of stepping through the MMC plugin dialog you can just do winkey+R `certmgr.msc` enter, or even simpler name your file with extension .cer or .crt (it can _contain_ either DER or PEM), doubleclick, and click InstallCertificate. Also, LE will not issue a cert for an IPaddress as apparently wanted here, and NO public CA (specifically no CABforum member) will issue a cert for a _private_ IPaddress as here (or a nonpublic domainname like whatever.local either).